# Getting cookie in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I'm trying to get cookie in servlet using

```
Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
```

but `cookie` is always `null`.

So I set them from another servlet and they appear in browser preferences.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("color", "cyan");
cookie.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: Does the browser access this other servlet using the same domain name, protocol and port (e.g. https://example.com:80).

Answer (score 17):

[According to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29) `getCookies()` Returns an array containing all of the Cookie objects the client sent with this request. This method returns null if no cookies were sent.

Did you add the cookie correctly? If yes, you should be able to iterate through the list of cookies returned with

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  String name = cookies[i].getName();
  String value = cookies[i].getValue();
}
```

If no...

Cookies are added with the `addCookie(Cookie)` method in the response object!

Comment: So I mean that I add cookie from another servlet and that servlet really adds cookie, but when i"m trying to get request.getCookie() returns null.

Comment: Note the "This method returns null if no cookies were sent.", The given code will fail with NullPointerException when doing cookies.length if getCookies() returns null.

Answer (score 14):

**SET COOKIE**

```
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookiename", "cookievalue");
  response.addCookie(cookie);
```

**GET COOKIE**

```
  Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
  if(cookies != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          cookie=cookies[i]
          String cookieName = cookie.getName();
          String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
       }
   }
```

Comment: able to read only the alphabets, not reading the alphanumerics or special symbols ? What may be the cause ?

Comment: what about add timelife to the cookie? it is possible¿?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the client supports cookies? because if it is configure to NOT accept cookies, you will never get them back on a following request...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered the cause in my case was that I was using the browser built into Eclipse.  This does not accept cookies.  When I accessed the same JSP from chrome, it worked.  Perhaps you are doing the same thing I did?

It may also be the case that the browser you are using or your internet settings are set to reject cookies.  Hope this helps you or any other visitor experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

firstly ,you should create a cookie,and then add to response

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name,value);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: I adds cookie this way from another servlet

Comment: @Anatoly Is the other servlet on your same domain and subdomain?