# Get cookie value in java

Tags: java, cookies

I've initialized cooke like this in my JSP,

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
String loc = "/u/poolla/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/"+timeStamp;
Cookie thecookie = new Cookie("thecookie", loc);
thecookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
response.addCookie(thecookie);
```

So, all the cookies created will have the same name, but different value for different user access time.

At the ending of java servlet I want to deactivate/kill the cookie that has been passed at the beginning of java servlet and say if they are 5 users using the system in parallel how will I know which cookie to deactivate for which user in the last of my.java?

for example, consider

```
User 1 : cookie name `thecookie` value `AAA`
User 2 : cookie name `thecookie` value `BBB`
User 3 : cookie name `thecookie` value `CCC`
User 4 : cookie name `thecookie` value `DDD`
User 5 : cookie name `thecookie` value `EEE`
```

Now, at the end of my.java servlet I want to deactivate the cookie with value CCC that has been assigned at the beginning of my.java without disturbing other cookie values, how to do this?

Comment: your second question in not clear.

Comment: Explained in my edit.

Comment: Web application is already multithreaded. Why are you thinking that it will show 10 cookies for ten users?

Comment: I didn't get you, I've just started with cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting cookie in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047548/getting-cookie-in-servlet)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are using the wrong method for reading the cookies..

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies != null) {
 for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
   if (cookie.getName().equals("cookieName")) {
     //do something
     //value can be retrieved using #cookie.getValue()
    }
  }
}
```

use this. No need to detect the cookie for particular user just deactivate it.

Comment: You mean it automatically identifies which cookie to deactivate??

Comment: I am not able to read the special character or numbers associated with the string in this method ? any restrictions ?

Comment: Added java 8 for the high rated answer:

Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).filter(t -> "cookieName".equals(t.getName())).findFirst().get()

Comment: what is `request` in this answer? how to define it?

Comment: @Kavipriya `request` refers to [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to get the cookie value without running the loop? I have a requirement where I need fetch the same cookie value twice in a single API call. I want to do with minimal code change. Please help me.

Comment: Filter the cookie and set it in a variable for further access

Answer (score 12):

Ready to use generic method:

```
public static Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals(name)) {
                return cookie;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
int i = 0;
for (Cookie cookie : cookies ) {

  Sytem.out.println(cookies[i].getName());
  Sytem.out.println(cookies[i].getValue());

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin it will be much shorter:

```
fun HttpServletRequest.getCookie( name: String) = cookies.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    AccountDAO db = new AccountDAO();
    Account ac = (Account) db.getAll(username, password);

    if (ac != null) {
        String remember = request.getParameter("remember");
        if (remember != null) {
            Cookie c_user = new Cookie("username", username);
            Cookie c_pass = new Cookie("password", password);

            c_user.setMaxAge(3600 * 24 * 30);
            c_pass.setMaxAge(3600 * 24 * 30);

            response.addCookie(c_user);
            response.addCookie(c_pass);

            session.setAttribute("display_name", ac.getDisplayName());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("display_name", ac.getDisplayName());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    // Get an array of Cookies associated with this domain
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].getName().equals("username")) {
                username = cookies[i].getValue();
            }
            if (cookies[i].getName().equals("password")) {
                password = cookies[i].getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    AccountDAO l = new AccountDAO();
    Account a = l.getAll(username, password);
    if (a != null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
       
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```