# Is it possible to get the cookie value over the application?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

I got a different requirement which I haven't tried before. Let's say I have two web applications which will run on same browser with localhost as a host. Can it possible to set the cookie value in my first web application and get the respective cookie value in my second web application?

If possible, How can I do the same?

I tried as follows, But I am getting `Cookie` value as `null`.

In my First Web application,

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("PortalUser", uName);
ck.setDomain("localhost");
ck.setMaxAge(30 * 60);
response.addCookie(ck);
```

In my Second Web application,

```
HttpSession mySession = request.getSession();
System.out.println(mySession.getAttribute("PortalUser"));//Value is printing null
```

Comment: Have you tried to achieve it the same way you fetch out cookies in a single web application ?

Comment: Well as long as the domain is same, you can access the cookies but it depends on how you're storing them. If they're `HttpOnly` cookies, then they're cleared for every 302 page redirects

Comment: `session.setAttribute(key,value)` will store the value in the corresponding `HttpSession` associated with the current request. That's not the way to store cookies. Have a look at Cookie API [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/cookies_api.shtml) and [here](http://way2java.com/servlets/java-servlet-cookie-api-methods/)

Comment: Do you've `javax.servlet-api.jar` in your build path ? If you're using Maven, add that dependency in your pom.xml, if not you can download it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1)

Comment: @Arkantos, I tried by adding jar file. But I am getting cookie value as null. I have updated my question. Can you please correct me what's wrong with my code

Comment: Capture `HttpServletRequest request` first, then use `request.getHeader("Cookie");`

Comment: Yup.. like user1354678 mentioned, you need to retrieve those cookie values from request either from the `header` or by using `request.getCookies()` as mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804409/get-cookie-value-in-java#22804563). Second one is easier as you don't have to tokenize the cookie string by yourself. Also MaxAge's argument is in seconds, so according to your code it's going to last only for 1800 seconds, try to give some big value for that

Comment: I tried the second procedure and print the output in logs. The cookie "PortalUser" is not set in the cookies. While printing the cookies I am able to see only one session varible name (JSESSIONID) and PortalUser is not set properly. Is there any issue while setting the cookie in web application 1.

Comment: Both your applications are running on localhost but with a different context path.. that's it right ? Also you're invoking webapp-1 URL first which will set the cookie and then you're running webapp-2 URL which will try to retrieve this cookie.. correct ?

Comment: @Arkantos Yes, Correct. Is there any issue If I do like that. Can you please suggest some solution OR any alternative way to get the session value.

Comment: Theoretically it's supposed to work ;) We usually do a hidden form post as SAML message in an empty redirect page when we want to send parameters from one application to another application (or) write to a file in a common location accessible to both the webapps. There're even better ways of doing it but these two are off the top of my head :)

Comment: @Arkantos I tried both the ways but no result. Is there any alternative way? need some suggestion please

Comment: Whenever the the browser accesses the web application it submits the cookies stored on the client machine to the web application. Only cookies stored by the accessed web application are submitted. Cookies from other web applications are not submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `CookieManager` and set its Cookie Policy to `ACCEPT_ALL` and then use `CookieHandler` to get the `Cookie` store.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
// Creates url for the given string
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://localhost/");
    // Opens a connection with the url specified and returns URLConnection object
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    // Gets the contents from this url specifies
    urlConnection.getContent();
} catch (MalformedURLException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Returns the cookie store(bunch of cookies)
CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
// Getting cookies which returns in the form of List of type HttpCookie
List<HttpCookie> listOfcookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
for (HttpCookie httpCookie: listOfcookies) {
    System.out.println("Cookie Name : " + httpCookie.getName() + " Cookie Value : " + httpCookie.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know the status

Comment: Do I need to add any jars? Got an an error, CookieManager is not resolved a type

Comment: It's of java.net.CookieHandler package so you don't need to import any jars.

Comment: It is not returning any cookie values, It is showing cookie list size as 0. Any suggestions ?

Comment: That means you have no cookies at all.