# Set Session Object in JavaScript for J2EE application

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, session-variables

I need to set the form field value in the session object using JavaScript like

```
function validateFields(){
var userEnteredPassword = document.getElementById("servicePassword").value;
<% session.setAttribute("UserPassword", userEnteredPassword  ); %>    
}
```

I declared the `<%@page language="java" session="true" %>` in page and unable to get the session values in the servlet.

As per my knowledge, we cant able to set the server side variables in client, but I need to achieve this type of functionality in my application.

Any alternatives for the same ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could get it from request.

Comment: Note that your code _renders_ the JavaScript snippet and getting `userEnteredPassword` is done on the client _after_ rendering on the server where `session.setAttribute("UserPassword", userEnteredPassword  );` is evaluated. You need the password to be sent back to the client - preferably via a form post - then get it from the request parameters. No need for JavaScript here.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, I am handling the file uploading along with this form and unable to handle the request object to read multiple times, so I found this alternatives. That way we can achieve. I am sure about it!

Comment: @Thomas, Can't use request parameters to get the control field values, made form as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload the file to the server.

Comment: You send that data as form-data so why shouldn't you be able to get it? Granted, `request.getParamter()` won't work but there are other ways to get the data. Have a look at at [Apache Commons Fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) for one way to do it.

Comment: I check, have some access limits here.

tried with the 
'@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig()' Annotations and working either file uploading or `request.getParameter("")` but unable to perform both at one request object

Comment: Handling with Cookies is a best way in Web app like J2EE ? Found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804563/4460282) useful. What you say about this ?