# how to save cookies and redirect in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

I get a task that to provide a login api , once user login, then i redirect to the index.html page, and save username as cookies.

I tried this but does not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/direct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", String.valueOf(RandomUtils.nextInt())));
   return "redirect:/index.html";
}
```

it redirect successed,but no cookies saved.

Comment: Why don't you use session ?

Comment: i need save something that the front ui page can use.

Comment: Check this out > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047548/getting-cookie-in-servlet

Answer (score 4):

I save the cookie when I set the path:

```
Cookie coocie= new Cookie("X-COOKIE-NAME", "val");
coocie.setPath("/");
httpResponse.addCookie(coocie);

String redirectURL = "http://localhost:...";
httpResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```